# Prove $\exists x(P(x) \land \forall y(P(y) \to y=x)) \vdash \exists x \forall y(P(y) \leftrightarrow y=x)$.

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, natural-deduction, formal-proofs

This is the skeleton for the proof of $\exists x(P(x) \land \forall y(P(y) \to y=x)) \vdash \exists x \forall y(P(y) \leftrightarrow y=x)$ using Fitch-style natural deduction system.

$
\def\fitch#1#2{\quad\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline#2\end{array}}
\def\Ae#1{\qquad\mathbf{\forall E} \: #1 \\}
\def\Ai#1{\qquad\mathbf{\forall I} \: #1 \\}
\def\Ee#1{\qquad\mathbf{\exists E} \: #1 \\}
\def\Ei#1{\qquad\mathbf{\exists I} \: #1 \\}
\def\R#1{\qquad\mathbf{R} \: #1 \\}
\def\ci#1{\qquad\mathbf{\land I} \: #1 \\}
\def\ce#1{\qquad\mathbf{\land E} \: #1 \\}
\def\ii#1{\qquad\mathbf{\to I} \: #1 \\}
\def\ie#1{\qquad\mathbf{\to E} \: #1 \\}
\def\be#1{\qquad\mathbf{\leftrightarrow E} \: #1 \\}
\def\bi#1{\qquad\mathbf{\leftrightarrow I} \: #1 \\}
\def\qi#1{\qquad\mathbf{=I}\\}
\def\qe#1{\qquad\mathbf{=E} \: #1 \\}
\def\ne#1{\qquad\mathbf{\neg E} \: #1 \\}
\def\ni#1{\qquad\mathbf{\neg I} \: #1 \\}
\def\IP#1{\qquad\mathbf{IP} \: #1 \\}
\def\x#1{\qquad\mathbf{X} \: #1 \\}
\def\DNE#1{\qquad\mathbf{DNE} \: #1 \\}
$
$
\fitch{1.\, \exists x(P(x) \land \forall y(P(y) \to y=x))}{
  \fitch{2.\, P(a) \land \forall y(P(y) \to y=a)}{
 3.\, P(a) \ce{2}
 4.\, \forall y(P(y) \to y=x) \ce{2}
 5.\, P(b) \to b=a \Ae{4}
 \fitch{6.\, P(b)}{
 b=a
}\\
\fitch{7.\, b=a}{
 \vdots\\
 P(b)
}\\
P(b) \leftrightarrow b=a\\
\vdots
}\\
 \exists x \forall y(P(y) \leftrightarrow y=x)
}
$

In order to use, $\mathbf{\leftrightarrow E}$, I need to show $P(b) \vdash b=a$ and $b=a \vdash P(b)$.

Is this the right approach? How can I justify $P(b)$ for the second subproof ?

EDIT:

**Biconditional Introduction and Elimination Rules**

$
\fitch{}{
 \fitch{i.\, \mathcal{A}}{
 j.\, \mathcal{B}
}\\
\fitch{k.\, \mathcal{B}}{
 l.\, \mathcal{A}
}\\
\, \mathcal{A} \leftrightarrow \mathcal{B} \bi{i-j,k-l}
}
$

$
\fitch{}{
  \mathcal{A} \leftrightarrow \mathcal{B}\\
  \mathcal{A}\\
  \mathcal{B} \be{m,n}
}
$

$
\fitch{}{
  \mathcal{A} \leftrightarrow \mathcal{B}\\
  \mathcal{B}\\
  \mathcal{A} \be{m,n}
}
$

**Identity elimination rules**

$
\fitch{}{
 \mathcal{a} = \mathcal{b}\\
 \mathcal{A}(...\mathcal{a}...\mathcal{a}...)\\
 \mathcal{A}(...\mathcal{b}...\mathcal{a}...)
}
\fitch{}{
 \mathcal{a} = \mathcal{b}\\
 \mathcal{A}(...\mathcal{b}...\mathcal{b}...)\\
 \mathcal{A}(...\mathcal{a}...\mathcal{b}...)
}
$

Comment: Which are the rules $\leftrightarrow_\mathrm{intro}$ and $\leftrightarrow_\mathrm{elim}$ in your system?

Comment: Just updated the post.

Comment: Which is the precise formulation of the rule $= \mathbf{E}$? Depending on that, I possibly have to add a line between lines 8 and 9 in my derivation.

Comment: I will update the post to include that piece of data.

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco, your use of $= \mathbf{E}$ is perfectly in line with my book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$
\def\fitch#1#2{\quad\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline#2\end{array}}
\def\Ae#1{\qquad\mathbf{\forall E} \: #1 \\}
\def\Ai#1{\qquad\mathbf{\forall I} \: #1 \\}
\def\Ee#1{\qquad\mathbf{\exists E} \: #1 \\}
\def\Ei#1{\qquad\mathbf{\exists I} \: #1 \\}
\def\R#1{\qquad\mathbf{R} \: #1 \\}
\def\ci#1{\qquad\mathbf{\land I} \: #1 \\}
\def\ce#1{\qquad\mathbf{\land E} \: #1 \\}
\def\ii#1{\qquad\mathbf{\to I} \: #1 \\}
\def\ie#1{\qquad\mathbf{\to E} \: #1 \\}
\def\be#1{\qquad\mathbf{\leftrightarrow E} \: #1 \\}
\def\bi#1{\qquad\mathbf{\leftrightarrow I} \: #1 \\}
\def\qi#1{\qquad\mathbf{=I}\\}
\def\qe#1{\qquad\mathbf{=E} \: #1 \\}
\def\ne#1{\qquad\mathbf{\neg E} \: #1 \\}
\def\ni#1{\qquad\mathbf{\neg I} \: #1 \\}
\def\IP#1{\qquad\mathbf{IP} \: #1 \\}
\def\x#1{\qquad\mathbf{X} \: #1 \\}
\def\DNE#1{\qquad\mathbf{DNE} \: #1 \\}
$

Your approach is correct, you just have to fill the dots (and fix a couple of typos in lines $2$ and $4$: $a$ should replace $x$).

To prove $b = a$ from $P(b)$ you just have to trivially apply *modus ponens* $\to \mathbf{E}$ from lines $5$ (i.e. $P(b) \to b = a$) and $6$ (i.e. $P(b)$).

Vice-versa, to prove $P(b)$ from $b = a$ you have to apply $= \mathbf{E}$ from lines 3 (i.e. $P(a)$) and 8 (i.e. $b = a$). Here we are using an obvious but important property of the identity $=$: if $P(a)$ and $b = a$ then $P(b)$.

So, you get $P(b) \leftrightarrow b = a$ by $\leftrightarrow \mathbf{I}$ and hence you are done by introducing first the universal quantifier and then the existential quantifier.

Note that the witness $a$ for both the existential quantifier in the hypothesis and the existential quantifier in the conclusion is the same. Indeed, the core of the proof is to prove that $P(a) \land \forall y \, (P(y) \to y = a) \vdash \forall y \, (P(y) \leftrightarrow y =a)$ (i.e. the derivation from the second line to the second to last line).

Below a complete proof in Fitch-style natural deduction.

$
\fitch{1.\, \exists x(P(x) \land \forall y(P(y) \to y=x))}{
  \fitch{2.\, P(a) \land \forall y(P(y) \to y=a)}{
 3.\, P(a) \ce{2}
 4.\, \forall y(P(y) \to y=a) \ce{2}
 5.\, P(b) \to b=a \Ae{4}
 \fitch{6.\, P(b)}{
   7. \, b=a \ie{5,6}
    }\\
    \fitch{8.\, b=a}{
   9. \, P(b) \qe{3, 8}
    }\\
    10. \, P(b) \leftrightarrow b=a \bi{6\text{-}7, 8\text{-}9} 
    11. \, \forall y \, (P(y) \leftrightarrow y = a) \Ai{10}
    12. \, \exists x \forall y\, (P(y) \leftrightarrow y=x) \Ei{11}
}\\
 13 .\, \exists x \forall y \, (P(y) \leftrightarrow y=x) \Ee{1,12}
}
$

Comment: Thank you very much, @Taroccoesbrocco ! Two little things in your proof. First, you didn't close the subproof you opened in line 2 for the existential quantifier. And, in order to use $\mathbf{\exists E}$ (to close the subproof), witness _a_ cannot appear in the last line of the subproof.

Comment: I really appreciate your dedication and explanation.

Comment: @F.Zer - Thank you for your remark, both issues are fixed by adding line 12 to my derivation, which I had forgotten.

Comment: It's perfect ! Thanks for the fixes.